# NSFetchedResultsController deleteCache in Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3

Currently migrating to swift 3 and can't quite figure out what the parser wants for `NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCache(withName: "rootCache")`

With this syntax, I'm getting a "Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'" error when building.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message is misleading. As of Swift 3, 
`NSFetchedResultsController` is a generic type

```
open class NSFetchedResultsController<ResultType : NSFetchRequestResult> : NSObject { }
```

and the following should work:

```
NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>.deleteCache(withName: "rootCache")
```